# How to use Windows Phone push notification launch page in a Phonegap App?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone, phonegap-pushplugin

I have a Phonegap App in which I have implemented push notifications with [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). When the user taps the received notification, I'm showing a local notification which contains a link(button) to a specific page based on the payload of the push notification. For this I'm using the notification callback method of course.

On Android and iOS everything is working fine. It also works if the WP application is open when the push notification is received. Where I'm having problems is when the app is not running and the toast is tapped, because the notification callback method is never fired. This is not unexpected, because I know that's normal behavior of WP.

What I'm trying to do instead is to set the `launch page` in the payload of the message. I'm using Telerik Backend services so I'm sending the message as specified in the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/backend-services/features/push-notifications/structure):

```
"WindowsPhone": {
    "Toast": {
        "Title": title,
        "Message": message,
        "LandingUri": uri
    }
}
```

When I inspect the received notification in the callback it looks like this:

```
{ 
    "jsonContent": {
        "wp:Text1": title,
        "wp:Text2": message,
        "wp:Param": uri
        },
    "type": "toast"
}
```

I have tried to set the `LandingUri` in multiple different ways, for example: 
`//www/index.html#api/my-page` and `x-wmapp0:www/index.html#api/my-page`
I'm using Backbone Marionette router, so that's why the url is set like this: #api/.
The problem is, it never lands on the page I try to set. Most of times it lands on the index page and sometimes the app crashes before it even starts. No error is received, it just shuts down.

I'm a total noob when it comes to Windows Phone, so my question is: **How should I set the uri of the landing page in the object?**

Alternatively, is there **any other way** to achieve the behavior I want, which is: navigating to a specific page inside my application based on an uri received in a push notification (after the toast is tapped and the application is not running)?

For additional information, I'm using Phonegap Build. I'm also more than happy to provide more info if needed.

I have spent hours on this and it has been very frustrating. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: What Version of Windows Phone are you targeting windows Phone 8 silverlight or windows phone 8.1?

Comment: Windows phone 8.1. I just found out that the `LandingUri` should be set to something like `"/MyPage.xaml"`, but Phonegap apps usually have only one phone application page. In my case there should be several and it seems like it might be impossible to achieve the functionality I'm looking for. Next I'm going to figure out if I could use the `OnNavigatedTo` method in the mainpage.xaml.cs as described in the [PushPlugin documentation](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#showtoastnotification-wp8-only). I'm not sure if this could be done when using PhoneGap Build?

Answer (score 1):

In your PhoneGap Build project you can add additional logic in the OnNavigatedTo method in the MainPage.xaml.cs file. If the method is not available, you can still override it.

Just add the logic in the link you quoted in your MainPage.xaml.cs. 
For instance:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) {
  base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
  try {
    var location = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["NavigateTo"];
    if (location!= null) {
      this.CordovaView.StartPageUri = new Uri ("//www/" + location, UriKind.Relative);
    }
  } catch (KeyNotFoundException) {}
}
```

Then after sending a push notification add the following value to the “LandingUri” field:

“/MainPage.xaml?NavigateTo=appnews.html”
where appnews.html is a HTML file in the www folder of your app. 
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I actually kind of gave up on this and went around the problem by changing the logic of my process on WP. Since I may still change my approach in the future, I would be very interested to know *how to override* the `OnNavigatedTo` method when using PhoneGap Build? If I understand correctly, I would have to make my own Plugin for that? Or another option would be to unpack the xap after the build, change the MainPage.xaml.cs and then somehow pack it again? The second one especially feels like a very bad option to me.

Comment: I've got a silly question. Im looking the whole day into wp8 notifications for cordova. Can somebody tell me where i can find (or need to make) the mainpage.xaml.cs file? Can't find it anywhere + can't find it on the internet :(

Comment: @peterdoesco.de When adding the Windows Phone platform in the Cordova project, the MainPage.xaml will be added automatically. In case you are using an IDE other than the Cordova CLI, the MainPage.xaml might be unavailable.

Comment: @d1mitar Thanks! I figured it out. Had the wrong platform. I was using windows. In windows you got windows phone so made a silly mistake :)

Comment: @peterdoesco.de great, sorry for the late response, i didn't see a notification for your comment :)

Comment: @d1mitar No worries man! Maybe you can help me with another question ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728490/cordova-deviceready-event-firing-twice-on-wp8