# Cordova 'deviceready' event firing twice on wp8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a WP8 application in Cordova.

I already finished the app in Android and iOS, but on WP8 the 'deviceready' event is firing twice? :(

- I tried to add a counter to ready, but the counter starts everytime on 0
- I tried it with a var r = false and if ready is called set to true. But r stays false
- I even tried a timer in ready with a random math. still nothing though

Still executing twice

> - Cordova version: 5.0.0
> - jQuery: 2.1.x

```
document.body.onload = onLoad;

function onLoad() {
    console.log('onload');
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', ready, false);
}

function ready(){
    console.log('ready'); //firing twice
}
```

The following cordova plugins are installed:

- 2.4.0 "PushPlugin"
- 1.0.0 "Console"
- 2.4.0 "PushPlugin"
- 1.0.0 "Console"
- 1.0.0 "Device"
- 1.0.0 "Notification"
- 1.0.0 "Geolocation"
- 1.0.0 "Globalization"
- 1.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
- 1.0.0 "Network Information"
- 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
- 1.2.0 "UniqueDeviceID"
- 3.2.2 "Custom URL scheme"
- 1.0.0 "Splashscreen"
- 0.3.13 "Vibration"
- 0.1.7 "AppVersion"

> And at last the debug information: http://pastebin.com/8FgLnULJ

Hope you guys can help me because I can't figure it out.

If someone needs more information, just ask me :)

Thanks!

Comment: No one can help me ? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change **console.log** to **alert** then you will see that *deviceready* fired once... Console plugin for windows phone just doing duplicate of messages, try remove the plugin and you will see one message "ready"...